# How to display a specific data from a database into textbox?

Tags: c#

```
public DataTable DisplayHolidays(int empid)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ComputeHoliday", myCon);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = empid;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rd.Read())
    {
        temp2 = rd[0].ToString();
    }
    return dt;
}
```

This is my code I had a problem/error with this part. This code is in the class not in the form load. It cannot display the data in the textbox. I'm using `temp2` to store the data in the selected row but it's not yet working.

Comment: What is the error?  What's not working?  Please describe the problem, including any *actual* errors or exceptions you receive.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're getting an exception at `cmd.ExecuteReader()`.

Note that you must open the connection before you can use the command in `cmd.ExecuteReader()`. `DataAdapter.Fill` does not need an open connection, the dataadapter will open/close it implicitly.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be
>   valid, but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed
>   before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If
>   the connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open.

---

Why do you use `DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)` and also `Command.ExecuteReader`? You need just one way to get the data. If you already have filled a table:

```
If(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    temp2 = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(0);
}
```

If you don't use the `DataAdapter` and the `DataTable` but only the reader:

```
using(SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if(rd.HasRows)
    {
        rd.Read();
        temp2 = rd.GetString(0);
    }
}
```